# swift In App Purchase issue with SKProduct

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, skproduct

I'm making an app with some IAP and I'm facing a boring issue which makes me feel insane.. 
I tested my IAP but it didn't work. (nothing happenned) I checked what's wrong and found the problem comes from the `SKProduct`.
So I'm trying to request a Product with `SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIds)` and then if I print:  `response.products.count` , the result will be `0`. (`response:SKProductsResponse`)

Here's my code to request the product :

```
class IAPHandler: NSObject {
static let shared = IAPHandler()

fileprivate var productID = ""
public var productIdentifiers:NSSet = ["com.company.app.IAP1","com.company.app.IAP2"]
public var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()
var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()

var purchaseStatusBlock: ((IAPHandlerAlertType) -> Void)?


func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }

func purchaseMyProduct(index: Int){

    print(iapProducts.count)

    if iapProducts.count == 0 { return } .    //// return 0 !

    if self.canMakePurchases() { .   //// return true

        let product = iapProducts[index]
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)


        productID = product.productIdentifier
    } else {

        purchaseStatusBlock?(.disabled)
    }
}  

 func fetchAvailableProducts(){

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)

    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()
  }
}
```

But `response.product` do not catch any values..

Does someone know what does it mean if my result is equal to `0`?
please help me to figure it out this issues. 
Do not hesitate to ask me more informations.

Comment: This is using Swift 3, but there's not much that's changed. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/in-app-purchase-tutorial-with-swift-3-ios-sdk--cms-27595 It walks you through everything from creating sandbox accounts to looking for products through purchases and restore purchases. One question - `productIds` is type `Set<String>`... what are you providing for that. You don't need to give the specific value(s) but at least the "format". Okay, second question. :-) Could you provide your code for this?

Comment: I invite you to read my edited question with an example of my code.

Comment: Commenting here instead of my answer. :-) You're doing something I haven't yet - multiple IAPs. Maybe try only one - if it finds it, you know the issue is related to how you are handling multiples. The other thing is I'm not seeing a call similar to my `fetchAvailableProducts`. You had it in your original code. Maybe you accidentally left it out in your edit?

Comment: Yes sorry I just added this function above. I also tried to set only one product Id but it still doesn't work.. the value is always returned to zero. I'll check again if the issue comes from the code or my iTunes Connect configuration even if i don't believe it.

Comment: One more thing - it's explained in the link in my first comment, but maybe you didn't do this. If the IAP isn't yet approved, you want to work in the iTuneConnect sandbox. You also probably *do not* want to use your Apple ID but instead create a sandbox account (or several for different regions and currencies for testing). Then from a device (I don't know if this works with the simulator) log into the app store with *that* account. Hope something works for you.

Comment: I've seen your link. But i've already all the itunes connect steps. But Thank you a lot for your precious time ! :-)

Comment: From what I can see, you've done the right things. When you figure it out post an answer to your own question - it'll help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK the answer is so simple..Someone told me to set the "agreements, tax and banking" Itunes connect informations...
Now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I use:

```
public var productIdentifiers:NSSet = "com.company.app.inapp1"
public var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()
var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()

func fetchAvailableProducts()  {
    let productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
    productsRequest.delegate = self
    productsRequest.start()
}

public func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
    if (response.products.count > 0) {
        iapProducts = response.products
    }
}
```

In the end, `iapProducts` is an array of available products.

I'm seeing two differences between the code you posted and this.

- I remember stumbling through creating a Swift `Set<String>` and finding that it works if you first set up a `NSSet` containing your products and then casiing it.
- Even after that, I was getting a zero return. Turns out I was using the "SKU" I had created, thinking it should work. I needed to make the StoreKit product ID be the product ID I set up in iTuneConnect - usually it's "com.company.app.iapname".

Comment: Thank you for the remarks! I've edited my question again with the whole class i'm using. it contain your advice about `NSSet`. For the product id, i'm not using the 'SKU' but the product Id i create for each IAP product.

Comment: @dfd In-app purchase is not working while face lock is enabled in iphone....
Any suggestions why it's not working?

Comment: @ParthBarot, no suggestions here. App Store purchases - all kinds - can be set up to use Face ID, but I'd think that this sort of thing is embedded in StoreKit and happens *after* you've passed processing into Apple's end. Sorry.